# How to get the text written in search field(type=search) in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to get the written text from the search text field after "go" button is pressed in mobile keyboard.

```
<input id="search" value="" type="search" name="search">
```

Here is javascript code.

```
$("input[data-type='search']").keyup(function (e) {
alert("pressed");
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
alert(code);
if (code == 13) {     //for "go" key
    //alert("pressed");
    alert($(this).val());
    $(this).trigger("keyup");
}
});
```

I am unable to get the typed text in the search field. I get "unsizeChanged:Enter, Ignore this event" in logcat. I am hoping for the successfully tested solution. Thank you.

Comment: `unsizeChanged:Enter, Ignore this event` this error occurs in **android** not in your jQuery.

Comment: this error is not bothering me. i am not getting the typed text on text field, and that is the one  i want to achieve. Thank you for your concern..

Comment: "go" button on soft keyboard? or is it a HTML button?

Comment: @Omar android phone keyboard..

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.  I modify my code by following:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function() { /* or pageinit for jQM 1.3 */
  $("[data-type='search']").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var text;
    if (code == 13) {
       text = $(this).val();
       alert(text);
    }
    else {
       return 1;  //this section avoid alert popouts, when other keys are pressed..
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What i think is you should change your selector little bit:

```
$("input[data-type='search']").keyup(function (e) {
```

change to this:

```
$("input[type='search']").keyup(function (e) { // type=search
```

or if your element's id is unique then you can try this:

```
$("#search").keyup(function (e) { // as id is unique so change the selector
    alert("pressed");
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which; // instead of ternary use it this way.
    alert(code);
    if (code === '13') {  //use "===" equals for strict check.
       //alert("pressed");
       alert($(this).val());
       //$(this).trigger("keyup"); // <----this should not be here so remove it.
    }
});
```

Comment: still i am not getting the result that i want. i am not sure whether i am handling the proper event or not..

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand you want enter to act as go

you should change this code

```
if (code == 13) {     //for "go" key
    //alert("pressed");
    alert($(this).val());
    $(this).trigger("keyup");
}
```

and prevent default action on the text field and trigger click on go button

```
if (code == 13) {     //for "go" key
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default action if enter is pressed
    //alert("pressed");
    alert($(this).val());
    //$(this).trigger("keyup"); //trigger click on button instead
$('#go-button').trigger('click'); 
}
```

Comment: i am already tried what you have suggested, but it doesn't work. i am afraid there is no any id="go-button"..

Comment: I'am suggesting you have a button with id='go-button' delete last line of code and try

Comment: actually, i want the result without defining a button after search textfield. I am trying to use "go" button of mobile keyboard as a submit button, for that a id can't be defined. Your suggestion can be an alternative though..

Comment: anyway make sure to use event.preventDefault(); since this will make sure that you will handle this event instead of default behavior

Answer (score 0):

Soft keyboard buttons e.g. arrows and "Done" or "Go" buttons has no `keyCode`. Even `blur` event don't fire on them as long as *Keyboard* is active.

Alternatively, you can listen to `focusout` event, which fires once an element loses focus and the *Keyboard* is acitve.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () { /* or pageinit for jQM 1.3 */
  $("[data-type=search]").on("focusout", function () {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

---

### Update

Based on your comment, Android's keyboard buttons has `keyCode`. You only need to bind events on `pagecreate` which is equivalent to `.ready()`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function() {
  $("[data-type='search']").on("keyup", function(e) { 
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which; if (code == 13) { 
      alert($(this).val()); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: sir, there are keycode for mobile keyword. I have modified your answer and get the result i want. Thank you sir, you have provided me a clue for my issue.what i do is:

    $(document).on("pagecreate", function() { /* or pageinit for jQM   1.3 */
 $("[data-type='search']").on("keyup", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == 13) {
   alert($(this).val());
  }
 });
    });

Comment: @RamGrg maybe Android has `keyCode` but iPhone doesn't. Glad it worked for you.